# Remove IPSEC policy from W2k3 DC

Tags: windows-server-2003, ipsec

I just can't for the life of me remember. We were setting up IPSEC for a VPN along time ago and added IPSEC that has always caused 1091 1085 errors. We are not using it so I would like to remove it but cant find where.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is probably better suited for http://serverfault.com so I have voted to automatically move it there. Once it gets 5 votes it will move automatically.

Comment: @raven - leave the tags for belongs-on-... they will be removed on the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this applies to a DC, but try this.

Snapin:

1) Log into the server
2) Start > Run prompt
3) secpol.msc
4) Go to the security policies on the server
5) Right-click the policy, click unassign

Command-line:

```
cmd /k netsh ipsec static show policy all
```

This will show if a policy is active or not

```
cmd /c netsh ipsec static delete all
```

This will remove everything from the policy store